why reading a parquet file creating a job in spark UI?
I am using this statement to read the parquet file in pyspark (without using any display function or show method later). When I go to Spark UI, I can see a job being created. How does not using any action create a job in spark?
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/C:/Users/username/Downloads/MTcars.parquet")

Below is what that is visible in jobs section in spark UI.


spark.read is a transformation that creates a DataFrameReader object but spark.load is an action which triggers the DataFrameReader to create a job and read the parquet file and returns a DataFrame object.

This is incorrect. First, 'load is a DataframeReader method, not a SparkSession method. Secondly, load is just a transformation, not an action. The job is submitted because the schema wasn't specified and Spark needs to fetch the Parquet Schema.

The job was submitted because Spark needs to fetch the Parquet Schema. No job will be submitted if you explicitly provide the schema instead.
df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(parquetSchema).load("/C:/Users/username/Downloads/MTcars.parquet")

